# pandas str match is not working after "+"

Tags: python, pandas

pandas str.match not working after "+".

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['a'] = ["Huwaei p30 4GB+256GB"]

b = df.loc[df['a'].str.match(f"Huwaei p30 4GB+256GB")]
c = df.loc[df['a'].str.match(f"Huwaei p30 4GB+")]

print('b: ', b)
print('c: ', c)
```

**b doesn't work, returns empty.**

**c works, detects the "+", returns the row**

Any idea? This is turning me crazy. How can I match the whole string with the "+".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b = df.loc[df['a'].str.match(f"Huwaei p30 4GB\+256GB")]
c = df.loc[df['a'].str.match(f"Huwaei p30 4GB\+")]
```

###### Output

```
b:                        a
0  Huwaei p30 4GB+256GB
c:                        a
0  Huwaei p30 4GB+256GB
```

Those are not doing pattern matching as per the regular expression provided. ([ref](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html))

Just for even clear understanding with your `match` pattern, if you change  original entry to be `df['a'] = ["Huwaei p30 4GB256GB"]` both will return the row since `+` in regex means it would match the preceding entry as many times as possible. To be more precise, in previous case it matches still
`Huwaei p30 4GB` and then it tries to match it multiple times but do not find anything but also it doesn't find a match for the next `2` character.

Comment: thanks! But I have a problem with that, the only way is to insert manually the "\" char? because I need to do a loop, therefore I need to insert \ before each "+". My current error is: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: @ToninoFernandez Can you ask a new question with the changes you made so far? and post a link here.

Comment: just solve it by adding replace('+','\+") into my criteria string! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `+` as it is a special regex character:

```
df.loc[df['a'].str.match(f"Huwaei p30 4GB\+256GB")]
```

Alternatively, if you do not need a regex, use `startswith`:

```
df.loc[df['a'].str.startswith(f"Huwaei p30 4GB+256GB")]
```

output:

```
                      a
0  Huwaei p30 4GB+256GB
```